# Which browsers allow popups on which events

Tags: browser, popup

Could we list how each of the major browsers support popups (i.e. open a new window, `target="_blank"`, etc.)

For ex: most allow popups on the `click` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rule of thumb is that popups are allowed ONLY in response to user-triggered events, of which click is the big one. Anything else gets blocked. Most browsers will further restrict things such that onmouseover would not trigger a popup, even though it's a user generated event. Basically, if the root cause of an event is NOT a physical click by the user, then it's blocked. This includes trying to do things like `$('#spam_me_to_death').click()`, as the click was not initiated by the user.